# vertical align multiline text in a responsive horizontal nav

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive

Trying to vertical align multi-line text(links) within a responsive horizontal list. The height of my nav is fixed.

My mark-up restructure is like this. You can see that all the links have even distributed width, if the container got smaller, the 3rd link item would run over multiple lines, how can I still get that to vertically align?

```css
.list {
  font-family: arial;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.list-item {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-item a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 48px;
  min-height: 48px;
  max-height: 48px;
}

.list-item a:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">one</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">two</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">three three three</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">four</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">five</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have situation where 3rd link will be in one line?! than you must use something like white-space: nowrap, if you want to show each "tree" line under line you need

```
.list-item {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: blue;
}

.list-item:hover {
    background: red;
}

.list-item a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /* line-height: 48px; */
    /* min-height: 48px; */
    max-height: 48px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does almost what you want. Only disadvantage: The actual link area (where you can click) doesn't span the whole height of the list elements (but the whole width):

EDIT: Added `a:focus` to the last rules selector after comment

```css
.list {
  font-family: arial;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.list-item {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: blue;
  height: 48px;
}
.list-item a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}
.list-item:hover, a:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">one</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">two</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">three three three</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">four</a></li>
  <li class="list-item"><a href="">five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I had a similar solution as well, unfortunately not desirable as I would like to preserve the hover, focus interaction with the link items even when interactive with a keyboard.

Comment: I added `a:focus` to the last rules selector after comment. Although this only highlights the `a` part on focus, it's still clearly visible.